# Oracle Timestamp based calculation on every day using Two datetime column

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table that contains two time stamp **t1(event open date)** and **t2(event close date)** and a primary key **eventid**.

If event is open then **t2** will be **null** whenever even gets closed the same row will be get updated with event closure date **t2**.
For example I want to check how many issues are open on every day bases on opened date **(t1)** from **01-apr-2016** to **10-apr-2016**.

I have to calculate how many events are open for every day based on a selected date range. 
Lets say if eventid 1 has got opened on **1st-APR** and got closed on **10th-APR** and I am calculating the number of opened issues for every day on **11th-APR** then it should give me number of open event 1 from 1st-APR to 10th-APR.

**Table Structure:-**

```
================================================
    EVENTID            T1               T2
================================================
       1           01-apr-2016      10-apr-2016
       2           02-apr-2016      08-apr-2016
       3           05-apr-2016      09-apr-2016
```

**Expected Output:-**

```
==============================================================================
       DATE            TOTAL_OPEN_EVENTS
==============================================================================
    01-apr-2016            1
    02-apr-2016            2(1 issue open on 1st(not closed on 2nd) and 1 on 2nd)
    03-apr-2016            2
    04-apr-2016            2
    05-apr-2016            3
    06-apr-2016            3
    07-apr-2016            3
    08-apr-2016            2(1 issue got closed on 8th(which was opened on 2nd))
    09-apr-2016            2
    10-apr-2016            0
```

How to do this kind of calculation in Oracle database ?

Comment: Please show example table data and expected output.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Added table structure and expected output.

Comment: Shouldn't count on 09-apr-2016 be 1, not 2? Event #3 is closed.

Answer (score 2):

In order to generate the end report, you need a row for each date in your desired range. You could either use a calendar table, if available, or I find using a query on `DUAL` using `CONNECT BY LEVEL < some_number` works well to generate rows on the fly. (In this case "some_number" will be the number of days you want to report on.)
From there, you just need to join the individual dates to the date ranges in your event table:

```
-- create table "events" table
create table event_date_ranges
as
select 1 as event_id, TO_DATE('2016-APR-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as start_date, TO_DATE('2016-APR-10', 'YYYY-MON-DD') as end_date from dual
union all
select 2 as event_id, TO_DATE('2016-APR-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as start_date, TO_DATE('2016-APR-08', 'YYYY-MON-DD') as end_date from dual
union all
select 3 as event_id, TO_DATE('2016-APR-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as start_date, TO_DATE('2016-APR-09', 'YYYY-MON-DD') as end_date from dual
;


with 
date_range_qry as 
(-- one way to set the start and end dates for your report
 select TO_DATE('2016-APR-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as report_start_date
      , TO_DATE('2016-APR-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as report_end_date
   from dual
)
, dates_qry
as
(
-- generate a row for all dates between 2016-APR-01 and 2016-APR-10
select report_start_date + ROWNUM - 1 as report_date
from dual 
     cross join
     date_range_qry drq
connect by level <= (drq.report_end_date - drq.report_start_date + 1)
)
select dq.report_date, count(edr.event_id) as total_open_events
  from dates_qry dq
       left outer join
       event_date_ranges edr
          on dq.report_date >= edr.start_date 
          and dq.report_date < edr.end_date
 group by dq.report_date
 order by dq.report_date
```

Output:

```
REPORT_DATE     TOTAL_OPEN_EVENTS
2016-APR-01     1
2016-APR-02     2
2016-APR-03     2
2016-APR-04     2
2016-APR-05     3
2016-APR-06     3
2016-APR-07     3
2016-APR-08     2
2016-APR-09     1
2016-APR-10     0
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this:

```
create table events_log
as
select 1 as event_id, TO_DATE('01-04-2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as T1, TO_DATE('10-04-2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as T2 from dual
union all
select 2 as event_id, TO_DATE('02-04-2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as T1, TO_DATE('08-04-2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as T2 from dual
union all
select 3 as event_id, TO_DATE('05-04-2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as T1, TO_DATE('09-04-2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as T2 from dual
;
--------------

select v.REPORT_DATE, count(t.EVENT_ID) as open_event
  from events_log t,
       (select to_date('01/04/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') + ROWNUM - 1 as report_date
          from dual
        connect by level <= (to_date('11/04/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') -
                   to_date('01/04/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') + 1)) v
 where t.T1(+) <= v.report_date
   and t.T2(+) >= v.report_date
 group by v.report_date
 order by v.report_date;
```

Output will be:

```
report_date open_event
01/04/2016  1
02/04/2016  2
03/04/2016  2
04/04/2016  2
05/04/2016  3
06/04/2016  3
07/04/2016  3
08/04/2016  3
09/04/2016  2
10/04/2016  1
11/04/2016  0
```